# Why does Pingdom Tools tell me to Compress components with gzip

Tags: asp.net, windows, compression, gzip, content-encoding

On Pingdom Tools I get a message to Compress components with gzip. We use asp.net on Windows 2016 server (IIS10). I have set in web.config the following

```
<httpCompression>
      <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="image/jpeg" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="image/png" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="image/svg" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </staticTypes>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="image/jpeg" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
      </dynamicTypes>
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" 
      dynamicCompressionLevel="8" />
    </httpCompression>
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
```

I have read that compressing jpg files might not be an advantage as it can actually make the file larger. I have gone through all files on the server and only jpg and png files do not have gzip or br set on content-encoding.

That leaves me with a few questions:

1. Why do the jpg files not show as content-encoding: gzip
2. Should I care about it?
3. If I should care, how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Compressing JPEG content makes no sense and hence shouldn't be done, because JPEG already optimize things in such a way that no useful compression can happen later on it. On the contrary, compressing PNG content can be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. PNG compression is already enabled, but still get these errors and thereby lower rating. Anyway, even though I have set add mimeType="image/png" enabled="true" it does not seem to compress them. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: "it does not seem to compress them." How do you test? Using a browser and development tools? Using a CLI HTTP client like `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: I see this by using Chrome F12 and see header information for each file.

Comment: I dont "do" Windows, but I wonder if it is referring to gzipping scg's, CSS, html and Javascript etc by way of a directive at the seever level?

Comment: I have tested on some Linux sites and they report gzip even on JPG files and thereby getting better grades. But if JPG is not required to get zipped, I will leave that for now. I would need advice on how to set it correctly for PNG files.